# Asp.net stay on right tabload

Tags: jquery, asp.net, pageload

I tried Jquery, I have tried everything on the web but it doesn't work, please tell me how can I implement this on my page so when I click something in the tab or the `grid view` on any tab it doesnt go to the first tab which it does now. Please dont tell me its repeated because i have tried the other solutions and it must be something im doing or implementing wrong.

here i have the bootstrap css

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Here i have my tabs in a navbar using bootstrap.

```
    <div class="container-fluid" >                
        <div class="navbar-header" >
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Aweibo</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li><a href="#1a" data-toggle="tab">Startsida</a></li>
            <li><a href="#2a" data-toggle="tab">Mina uppgifter</a></li>
            <li><a href="#3a" data-toggle="tab">Användare</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#4a">Barn/ungdomar<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#1c" data-toggle="tab">Aktuella</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#2c" data-toggle="tab">Avslutade</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#3c" data-toggle="tab">Arkiverade</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#4c" data-toggle="tab">Registrera nytt barn</a></li>
```

there is a bit more tabs but this should give an idea